# Code editors with modal syntax highlighting

Tags: editor

Do any of the code editors, IDEs, etc, offer many different modes of syntax highlighting to be switched on briefly during refactoring missions to make certain identifiers or sentences really stand out to aid refactoring or just aid moving bits of code around for readability?

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any editor that does this by default, but it is certainly possible to add modes to, say, emacs, specifically for this purpose.